# Best option to read data from an external source to a C# program?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sqlite, epplus

I have a C# program that needs to read in an store external data and store within the classes to be called upon by the program at various stages of the programs execution. The storage of the data isn't a big issue as its only about 50 strings and it'll never be more than that so some structure like a dictionary (what I have been using) is perfect. The external data is basically user options that need to be changed from time to time by the person using the program

There are two main requirements for the method of reading and storage the external data.

1) The information **has** to be external.

2) The information has to be able to be changed with relative easy for people with absolutely no programming skills and very little IT skills in general.

So far I have come up with a few methods but they all have disadvantages to the point where I feel there might be a better option that I'm just not seeing?

I have tried using a text file and simply using dilimiting characters to identify the data for example: `optionName=OptionData`

I have tried using an excel file and using EPPlus to identify the data. This makes it a lot less messy and I can use colours etc to make the spreadsheet easier to use.

Both these methods fall with the same problem. The text file or excel file needs to be in the file directory for the code base and it could potentially get messy for the user to use and if there are multiple versions of the spreadsheet flying about it could be a problem.

Configuration files would be perfect if it wasn't for the second requirement.

The last route that I have tried is using a self contained database, namely SQLite, this however falls under the same roof as the text and excel files I feel. However I am new to SQLite and maybe I'm wrong?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. I don't this is a very uncommon problem so maybe other people have faced and overcame this issue before?

Comment: Can the data be on a network share somewhere? Is there some reason that it must be in the same directory as the executable? Or, you said "the file directory for the code base." You mean the source directory? But it seems unreasonable that the executable would be running from the same directory as the source. ... Your requirements are confusing.

Comment: Sorry if its confusing but yes the data can be on a network share but people might need the data on their individual machines and need to edit the data in a different way and then the whole thing gets out of control.

Comment: Use a config file, then write a GUI the people using the program can use to update the config file.

Answer (score 1):

> Configuration files would be perfect if it wasn't for the second requirement

I Really hate to tell you, but whateve you come up with in a file IS a configuration file and your only way to make it easy to edit for someone with no respect for form is to write an editor and that will cost (time and money).

I would not go with some sql program for that - on top, it will not solve the issue of having an editor.

XML File, mapped to a class, plus a small winform based editor is as good as it gets.

Comment: Well this is depressing... Personally I feel the excel spreadsheet is the best route due to the colours and grid etc. It just makes it a lot easier I feel.

Comment: Seriously? I have seen people with "no it experience" getting handed a excel sheet to fill out data. It ended with "search routines" looking for fields with sensible values "AROUND" the place where they should put it. No joke. The universe is very busy building people that are not smart enough to fill out a form if they are allowed to "f*** it up". A hommade program can run a LOT more validation.